# Assign different folder and file names from directory to variable in batch

Tags: batch-file, search, findstr

I am trying to assign different folder names from a given directory to different variables.

I am able to do the same in unix but its looking difficult to achieve from batch. Below is the unix code. In file changed.txt I have number of lines as below

> ```
> branches/abc/xyz/components/ADAdapter/release/post_commit_hook.zip
> branches/abc/xys/components/ADAdapter/release/post_commit_hook.zip
> branches/abc/xyz/components/ADAdapter/release/post_commit_hook.zip
> branches/abc/xyz/components/ADAdapter/release/post_commit_hook.zip
> ```

```
for x in `cat changed.txt`
do
a=`echo $x |egrep -i 'release'|egrep -i 'zip'| sed 's/.*release\///'| 
sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' `
b="$b,$a"
c=`echo $x | cut -d "/" -f1`
d=`echo $x | cut -d "/" -f5`
e="$e,$c"
f="$f,$d"
done
PACKAGE=`echo $b | sed 's/[,]//'`
BRANCH=`echo $e | sed 's/[,]//'`
UPDATEFOLDER=`echo $f | sed 's/[,]//'`
echo PACKAGE is $PACKAGE
echo BRANCH is $BRANCH
echo UPDATEFOLDER is $UPDATEFOLDER
```

I am expecting this output

> ```
> PACKAGE is post_commit_hook.zip,post_commit_hook.zip,post_commit_hook.zip,post_commit_hook.zip
>
> BRANCH is branches,branches,branches,branches
>
> UPDATEFOLDER is ADAdapter,ADAdapter,ADAdapter,ADAdapter
> ```

Can anyone help me in doing the same with Batch?

Comment: If the filepaths in `changed.txt` have a pattern, *(like in your example)*, you could use a `For /F` loop and select the `Tokens` based upon the **`/`** delimiter. In your example those would be `Tokens=1,5,7`. Open a Command Prompt window, and enter `For /?` to read the usage information for the command.

Comment: @Compo I could have done that. But as you can see how i am trying to extract value of  `a`. Its fine with me to take values from `token=1,5`, But for 7th token it has to be under `release folder` and that too it should be a `*.zip file`. Is it possible to do something for `$a` value to get it like the way I did above?

Comment: Please regard that this site is not a free code translation service, so please [edit] your question and include your attempts to solve it on your own! Also read the [tour] and these help articles: [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example based off my comment:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Rem This Undefines the variables
For %%A In (PKG BRN UPD) Do Set "%%A="

Rem This will propagate the variables
For /F "Tokens=1,5,7 Delims=/" %%A In (
    'FindStr /I "\/release/.*\.zip$" "changed.txt"'
) Do (
    If Defined BRN (Set "BRN=!BRN!,%%A") Else Set "BRN=%%A"
    If Defined UPD (Set "UPD=!UPD!,%%B") Else Set "UPD=%%B"
    If Defined PKG (Set "PKG=!PKG!,%%C") Else Set "PKG=%%C"
)

Rem This will show the variables with their content
For %%A In (PKG BRN UPD) Do Set %%A 2>Nul

Pause
```

**[Edit /]**
As a result of [acronicks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10769254/acroniks) comments, here's a version which should suffice in the event of the file using `LF` line endings or not being terminated with a standard `CRLF` ending. It also changes the variable names to match those in the question.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Rem This Undefines the variables
For %%A In (PACKAGE BRANCH UPDATEFOLDER) Do Set "%%A="

Rem This will propagate the variables
For /F "Tokens=1,5,7 Delims=/" %%A In (
    'More "changed.txt"^|FindStr /I "\/release/.*\.zip$"'
) Do (
    If Defined BRANCH (Set "BRANCH=!BRANCH!,%%A") Else Set "BRANCH=%%A"
    If Defined UPDATEFOLDER (Set "UPDATEFOLDER=!UPDATEFOLDER!,%%B") Else Set "UPDATEFOLDER=%%B"
    If Defined PACKAGE (Set "PACKAGE=!PACKAGE!,%%C") Else Set "PACKAGE=%%C"
)

Rem This will show the variables with their content
Echo PACKAGE is %PACKAGE%
Echo BRANCH is %BRANCH%
Echo UPDATEFOLDER is %UPDATEFOLDER%

Pause
```

**[Edit2 /]**
Here's a small modification to allow for the command to be saved to a variable first, *due to comment*.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Rem This Undefines the variables
For %%A In (PACKAGE BRANCH UPDATEFOLDER) Do Set "%%A="

Rem This will propagate the variables
Set "a=More "changed.txt"|FindStr /I "\/release/.*\.zip$""
For /F "Tokens=1,5,7 Delims=/" %%A In ('"%a%"') Do (
    If Defined BRANCH (Set "BRANCH=!BRANCH!,%%A") Else Set "BRANCH=%%A"
    If Defined UPDATEFOLDER (Set "UPDATEFOLDER=!UPDATEFOLDER!,%%B") Else Set "UPDATEFOLDER=%%B"
    If Defined PACKAGE (Set "PACKAGE=!PACKAGE!,%%C") Else Set "PACKAGE=%%C"
)

Rem This will show the variables with their content
Echo PACKAGE is %PACKAGE%
Echo BRANCH is %BRANCH%
Echo UPDATEFOLDER is %UPDATEFOLDER%

Pause
```

Comment: Is it possible to assign value of `'FindStr /I "\/release/.*\.zip$" "changed.txt"` to any variable?

Comment: Does the content of the three variables match that from your provided `$PACKAGE`, `$BRANCH` and `$UPDATEFOLDER` ones?

Comment: Actually the code I provided is the small snippet of my big code. I am trying to merge both code. And I am trying to merge your code into mine with some modifications. 

I am getting error while executing the same. That's why I asked if I can assign it into variable?

Comment: @acroniks, I asked a simple question and I'm not willing to expand or modify the above answer, without you confirming the answer to that question. Please run my provided script, as is, and provide the required response.

Comment: Not exactly. Output of your code is coming as  below

`PKG=post_commit_hook.zip,post_commit_hook.zip,post_commit_hook.zip
BRN=branches,branches,branches
UPD=ADAdapter,ADAdapter,ADAdapter
Press any key to continue . . .`

Which is printing each variable names 3 times only. And I am having 4 entries in changed.txt

Comment: So the answer to my question is **yes**, _(the last one is missing because your file doesn't terminate properly, **it should end it with a line return**)_. If you see my last `Rem`ark, you should read what it says because you probably don't wish to use that particular command in your script, you would probably wish to do it the same as in your unix script, i.e. `Echo PKG is %PKG%`, `Echo BRN is %BRN%` and `Echo UPD is %UPD%`. If you wish, there's nothing to stop you from changing all instances of, `BRN` to `BRANCH`, `UPD` to `UPDATEFOLDER` and `PKG` to `PACKAGE`.

Comment: Please see my **[Edit /]**, which should account for the above.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It works the way i wanted I have accepted your answer. But I also wanted to know that is it also possible to assign value of 'FindStr /I "\/release/.*\.zip$" "changed.txt" to any variable? Just like I did in above bash script a=`echo $x |egrep -i 'release'|egrep -i 'zip'| sed 's/.*release\///'| 
sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' ` . Can you help me out with this please?

Comment: @acroniks, it doesn't work like that in a batch script, you can only set a variable value to a string, not a command. Whilst it is possible to `Set` a variable to the command first, you would still have to run that command and save its output at run time. I have included a final example as **[Edit2 /]**, to show you it in use.